# Vim change block cursor when in insert mode

Tags: linux, shell, vim

Not sure what the terminology is for it but on Vim the 'cursor' is always like an insert/replace cursor instead of the blinking line cursor I'm used to in other gui editors. Is there any way to change this when in insert mode?

Comment: Are you using text mode Vim, or the GUI gVim?

Comment: Vim on my remote machine using iterm.

Comment: Please don't [cross-post](http://serverfault.com/questions/225977/vim-how-to-change-the-cursor-from-char-block-to-pre-pipe-line).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was connecting using iTerm on mac. It seems there is a setting in iTerm for it. Quick change and its working.

Comment: What was the setting and where is it? I'm looking for this as well but not seeing it in iterm2

Comment: It's a bit late, but maybe it helps someone
https://hamberg.no/erlend/posts/2014-03-09-change-vim-cursor-in-iterm.html

Answer (score 12):

I know this is an old question but hopefully this will help anyone else facing the same scenario.

Actually I'm using iTerm2 and using Vim inside my terminal on Mac. And when entering to insert mode, the cursor still being a block and is kind of confusing when you are at insert mode or normal mode.

I wanted to show a thin line as cursor when in insert mode and back to block when in normal mode as MacVim does. And to do so it's pretty simple, just added this to my `.vimrc` file as [described here](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Change_cursor_shape_in_different_modes):

```sh
let &t_SI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=1\x7"
let &t_SR = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=2\x7"
let &t_EI = "\<Esc>]50;CursorShape=0\x7"
```

[image]

But as you can see there was a delay when hitting `ESC` to exit insert mode back to normal mode and show the block as cursor again. So to fix it I found this:

```sh
set ttimeout
set ttimeoutlen=1
set listchars=tab:>-,trail:~,extends:>,precedes:<,space:.
set ttyfast
```

And now it works pretty fine as you can see:

[image: fix delay going back to block as cursor]

I hope it could help any one else!

Comment: Thank you so much for this. Do you have any idea why my cursor doesn't flash? I am using vim on iTerm2 on Mac.

Comment: @Aidenhsy maybe you need to activate this feature, go to `Preferences > Profiles > Select you profile on the left side > Select Text tab on the right > Check Blinking cursor option`. Hope it helps!

Comment: For me, these `&t_SI &t_SR &t_EI` escape sequences didn't work, but the sequences in this [answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/9133/27583) did.

Answer (score 4):

The gcr option does this, although I'm not sure exactly how it needs to be set to get the results you want.

```
:help gcr
```

If you read the manual and play around with it, you should be able to figure it out.

The blinking cursor in insert mode is usually the default. Maybe the gcr option got changed in your .vimrc

Answer (score 0):

This plugin for vim will actually change the cursor on the fly in iterm (and tmux)

It has a few bugs if you're in tmux, but works great outside of it: https://github.com/sjl/vitality.vim